# Redshift Scheduled queries - Error Alerts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-sns

I'm using Scheduled queries in order to run daily SQL scripts.
How can I create an alert (via email or similar) only if the script failed? I want to be able to monitor failures (if occurred) in order to fix them right away.

I tried SNS but I couldn't make a condition to send alerts only for failures.